# When Is This Sequence Monotone?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, multivariable-calculus

Let $p_n=a^n+b^n$ where $a$, $b$ are positive reals, $n\in \mathbb N$. What is the subset of $(a,b)\in \mathbb R_+^2$ for which $p_n$ is monotonically increasing?

I am mostly interested in an approach that can be generalized to the case of $k$-tuples $(a_1,a_2,...,a_k)$ to study the monotonicity of $p_n=a_1^n+a_2^n+...+a_k^n$, $n\in \mathbb N$. But even the case $k=2$ is interesting.

Comment: For all $n$ or sufficiently large $n$?

Comment: @njguliyev: for all $n$.

Comment: You want to compare $a^{n-1}+b^{n-1}$ to $a^n+b^n$. Clearly if $a,b<1$, then the sequence is decreasing. If $a,b>1$, then clearly it is increasing. What happens when one of them is greater than $1$ but the other is not? Can you say anything with any certainty about the sequence for small values of $n$ in this case?

Comment: @Cameron Williams: I can say that it not always monotone. I want to describe the set of parameters $(a,b)$ which render the sequence increasing as explicitly as possible.

Answer (score 0):

The interesting cases are $a\lt 1$, $b\gt 1$ (and $a\gt 1$, $b\lt 1$). We look only at $a\lt 1$, $b\gt 1$.

We want monotonicity to fail. So we are interested in the inequality $a^{n+1}+b^{n+1}\lt a^n+b^n$, or equivalently 
$$a^{n}(1-a)\gt b^n(b-1).\tag{1}$$ 
If Inequality (1) holds at a particular $n$, it holds for all smaller $n$. So the problem reduces to the inequality $a^2+b^2\lt a+b$, for $a\lt 1$ and $b\gt 1$.

Consider the disk $(a-1/2)^2+(b-1/2)^2 \lt \frac{1}{2}$. If we are inside the part of this disk, with $a\lt 1$ and $b\gt 1$, then the sequence $(a^n+b^n)$ fails to be monotonically increasing at some $n$. The region can be readily identified visually.  (In the long run it is monotonically increasing.)